# Core Data EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I've got my own Core Data function, which fetches data. This func is identical to my previous one, except entity names. Previous works great, but this fails with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to get data from `fetchedData` .

```
func fetchGroups() -> Array<Group> {
    var groups: Array<Group> = []
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Public> = Public.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor.init(key: "publicTitle", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) {
        for i in 0...fetchedData.count-1 {
            print(fetchedData[0])
            var group: Group = Group()
            group.groupName = fetchedData[i].publicTitle
            group.groupPhoto = fetchedData[i].publicPhoto
            group.groupID = Int(fetchedData[i].publicID)
            groups.append(group)
        }
        return groups
    }
    else {
        return groups
    }
}
```

So if it executes the code in brackets after `if (!fetchedData.isEmpty)`, array isn't empty. Why it fails on getting elements?

P.S. `fetchedData.count` = 1; But `fetchedData[0]` = BIG CRASH! Magic.

Comment: Maybe context doesn't provides array type at this point. Could you change  var groups: Array<Group> = [] to var groups: [Group] = [Group]()

Comment: How do you know that the individual fields of the groups have been correctly populated?

Comment: @Adolfo it breaks on reading fetchedData, not groups

Comment: @Feldur code breaks on reading the array, which was checked for emptiness. It's not empty, why it doesn't show me it's content?

Comment: Are you saying that the print call itself does not work?

Comment: @Feldur yep, after print it crashes. Or if there is no print, it crashes  after group.groupName = fetchedData[i].publicTitle.

Comment: Have you examined the content of the three individual elements using the debugger? I specifically mean public title photo and ID

Comment: @Feldur you mean print(fetchedData[0].publicTitile)? I did it, no result. It's funny, that "isEmpty" says that it's not empty; "count" tells me that there is 1 object and after all I can't access this 1 object not even by simple [0], even by using "description"

Comment: Don't use those obsolete forms like the index based for loop in Swift. Replace the empty check line and the for loop with `for item in fetchedData { ...`. `item` is the equivalent to `fetchedData[i]`.  If the array is empty the loop will be skipped anyway. And in case you have no choice to use an index based for loop use the half open operator `for i in 0..<fetchedData.count`.

Comment: @vadian the same effect. Un debugger after crash I try to print description of item and I get:
Printing description of item:
(MyApp.Public) i = <variable not available>

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint and get a more precise description about the reason of the exception.

Comment: Do this: 'for x in fetchedData; print(x)' and see what you get (replacing your loop). You could try x.publicTitle being printed too.

Comment: @vadian exception breakpoint shows no errors. I know the line where it crashes. It crashes right after some actions with fetchedData content. Like I said before, I have identical function with another Entity, which works great and allows me to use "description" etc. It is disappointing

Comment: @Feldur same issue(

Answer (score 3):

After a long research I found that the problem was too little but very hard to find. I just checked my coredata.xcdatamodeld file and noticed, that Public entity doesn't have Class definition. By default all entities have only names.